# No se reflejan mis variaciones de producto en WooCCommerce al importar

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy importando un producto variable a mi tienda online con WooCommerce pero no toma las variaciones y  por ello me dice que el producto ni tiene existencia de inventario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](imagen del producto en el excel)

---

- Ahora, cuando veo el producto en WordPress veo  que los  atributos no se están tomando para usar para  variaciones y parece que ahí está el verdadero error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura del Excel la saqué de la exportación de un producto que ya está subido y funciona a la perfección, en ese producto me basé para crear este

Intenté importar un producto variable por medio de WooCommerce pero no puedo hacer que los atributos se tomen para usar para variaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]